# What is the ratio of $\tan 37° / \tan 54°$?

Tags: trigonometry

I was asked this question in my class test with the following choices.

Ratio of $\tan 37° / \tan 54°$

$ 1) 3^2 : 4^2 $
$ 2) 4 : 3$
$ 3) \sqrt 3 : 2 $
$ 4) \sqrt 3 : 1 $

I was not given any tables. How to find the values?

Comment: None of these. Sure you typed it in correctly?

Comment: tan x>1 if x>45, tan x <1f x<45. So (tan 37)/(tan 54) <1. So 2),3),4) cannot be solutions. But my calculator says (tan 37)/(tan 54)=0.54748906... != 0,5625=9/16

Comment: @miracle173: $\sqrt{3}/2 < 1$ so 3) can be a potential answer but it's not

Comment: @miracle173 then it's $3^2:4^2$ which is $9:16$

Comment: @miracle173 More simply, the tangent is increasing over $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$; since $0<37^\circ<54^\circ$, we have $\tan(37^\circ)/\tan(54^\circ)<1$. This applies also to $\tan(37^\circ)/\tan(39^\circ)$, for instance.

Comment: tan45 = 1. If we add 8 with 37 and subtract 8 with 54 we get 45. Is there anything possible in this way?

Comment: @agriz you are correct to notice that $$\frac{\tan(45-k)}{\tan(45+k)}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$ however you will struggle to find $a$ and $b$ given $k=8$, they are almost certainly irrational

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoever wrote this class test is being very unhelpful. They actually want the ratio of

$$\frac{\tan(36.86989765...)}{\tan(53.13010235...)}$$

And that is $$\frac {\tan(\arctan(\frac34))}{\tan(\arctan(\frac43))}=\frac {9}{16}$$

So the ratio is $3^2:4^2$